# std::hash::operator() - where is exception guarantee?

Tags: c++, exception, hash, language-lawyer

Where in the standard does it specify that

```
std::hash<T>::operator()
```

will not throw any exception?

Answer (score 1):

This covered under [unord.hash]/4

> satisfy the requirement that the expression `h(k)`, where `h` is an object of type `hash<Key>` and `k` is an object of type `Key`, shall not throw an exception unless `hash<Key>` is a user-defined specialization that depends on at least one user-defined type.

So, as long as you are using one of the standard supplied specializations for [fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), `operator()` will not throw.